# order of an element in a subgroup

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and suppose $H$ is generated by an element $x$ of order $6$. Then for any $y \in G$ what are the possibilities for $yxy^{-1}$ ? My guess is that since $yxy^{-1} \in H$, its order divides $6$. So the possibilities are either it is $x$ or $x^2$ or $x^3$. Is this correct or can we eliminate any of the above options ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Observe that conjugation is an automorphism of the group. What does that say for the order of an element?

Comment: Ok, so that means it is of order $6$. So it is either $a$ or $a^5$. Thanks.

Comment: @KesavKrishnan Please put your comment into an answer so the question doesn't look unanswered, and **icmes** can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer was made in a comment by @Kesav Krishnan
"Observe that conjugation is an automorphism of the group. What does that say for the order of an element?"
I am posting it as a community wiki so the question shows an answer.